# separating tables through css and html

Tags: html, css

I am brand new to web development and coding and i was wondering what is the code to separating two of the tables? Which is a couple of lines down?

```
<table border="1" width="35%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><h3>Future Car's</h3></th>
    <td>Lincoln</td>
    <td>BMW</td>
    <td>Mercedes</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
 <th colspan="2"><h3>Plan's for the future</h3></th>
    <td>Web Development Job</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>Create web sites</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "separating two of the tables"? Do you want them to be side-by-side with some white space in between or on top of each other with some vertical space?

Comment: You only have one table in the code above. With some guessing as to what you want and are trying to acheive, i think you just want to add an extra <tr>&nbsp;</tr> between your current two table rows

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me out. Not vertical but horizontal space. Can you separate the table rows? Yeah, you are right its only one table. I am going to try that out <tr>&nbsp;</tr>     Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create two separate tables. I'd advise you to do all your styling in a separate css file and include it in your html for a cleaner code.

```
<table border="1" width="35%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
 <tr>
 <th colspan="2"><h3>Future Car's</h3></th>
 <td>Lincoln</td>
 <td>BMW</td>
 <td>Mercedes</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th colspan="2"><h3>Plan's for the future</h3></th>
 <td>Web Development Job</td>
 <td>San Francisco</td>
 <td>Create web sites</td>
 </tr>

</table>
<table border="1" width="35%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5">
 <tr>
 <th colspan="2"><h3>Future Car's</h3></th>
 <td>Lincoln</td>
 <td>BMW</td>
 <td>Mercedes</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th colspan="2"><h3>Plan's for the future</h3></th>
 <td>Web Development Job</td>
 <td>San Francisco</td>
 <td>Create web sites</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

This will give you a 20px distance between your tables. You can adjust it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood well enough you want to **separate the rows**, a quick way to do it is making a empty column with colspan of 3 and height of your liking; you can fill it with `<br />` too,  `&nbsp` is a non breaking space.

```
<table border="1" width="35%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><h3>Future Car's</h3></th>
        <td>Lincoln</td>
        <td>BMW</td>
        <td>Mercedes</td>
    </tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="30px">&nbsp</td>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><h3>Plan's for the future</h3></th>
        <td>Web Development Job</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>Create web sites</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```